# Need Hardware Sizing guidelines for SSAS Tabular server

Tags: ssas-2012

Are there any good sources of hardware sizing guidelines for servers running SSAS Tabular?  Something along the lines of "if your models are estimated to be this big (in terms of memory) and you're expecting and average x-number of simultaneous connections...here's what you should start out with".

obviously they need more memory than most other systems to hold the data...but I'd also expect them to be able to take advantage of more cores and higher clock speeds...once it's in memory, its really just a matter of ripping through it and crunching the numbers.  More cores to handle more concurrency, higher clock-speed for faster "crunching".

Comment: down vote, seriously?  please at least explain why my question is off-topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're supposed to aim for 40% of the memory size of the original database. 1tb data = 400gb ram for SSAS Tabular.

Comment: Thanks Aaron.  There's also some good information in Chapter 17 of the Russo, Ferrari, Webb book (SQL Server 2012 Analysis Services: The BISM Tabular Model)

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, Microsoft just released a whitepaper (Jan 2013) that addresses this material

[Hardware Sizing a Tabular Solution (SQL Server Analysis Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj874401.aspx)